# Async and await callout to firebase is not waiting

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I have a dating-like app and I want to be able to query for new matches every time a user clicks on the "connection" tab button.

I am not sure if I am writing the await or async incorrectly but if the user moves too fast for the database to return the results, the returned matches are not loaded fast enough. What I have so far is: on the load of the page I callout to Firebase, when the user navigates away and then navigates back to the "connection" tab, I call back out to Firebase. the `getMatches()` method is the callout to firebase.

```
const MatchesScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const {state, updateDislikedQueue, updateLikedQueue, getMatches} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [queue, setQueue] = useState({});
  const [noMatches, setNoMatches] = useState(false);
  const [updateProfileAndPreferences,setUpdateProfileAndPreferences] = useState(false);

const getMatchesMethod = async () => {
    getMatches().then(matches => {
      if (!matches) {
        Alert.alert("Update Preferences and Profile before connecting");
        setUpdateProfileAndPreferences(true);
      } else {
        setUpdateProfileAndPreferences(false);
        let cardData = [];
        for (m in matches) {
          if (matches[m].id == state.id) {
            continue;
          } else {
            let user = {
              id: matches[m].id,
              fullName: matches[m].info.fullName
            };
            cardData.push(user);
          }
        }
        if (cardData.length > 0) {
          setQueue(cardData);
          setLoaded(true);
        } else {
          setNoMatches(true);
          Alert.alert("No Connections Available");
        }
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMatchesMethod();
    const unsubcribe = navigation.addListener("willFocus", () => {
      getMatchesMethod();
    });
    // return unsubcribe.remove(); 
  }, []);
```

Also when I try to unsubscribe, the listener doesn't appear to work when the user navigates back and forth. Any help on what I am doing wrong with the async calls and the listener would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I was on V3 of react-navigation which is severely outdated was was conflicting with my react-native and expo versions.

I am in the process of updating everything (RN > .60, EXPO sdk > 35, @react-navigation V5) and will be able to use the listeners for @react-navigation v5 on my getMatches() method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just forgot the await keyword in your function 
Happens to me all the time ahaha

Comment: where do you think I forgot it? I am using a callback inside of the method `getMatches().then` and I am not allowed to put a callback inside of a `useEffect()`...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the `await` keyword in front of getMatches() instead of the .then() syntax. It makes the code read more synchronously, and it can help prevent errors. Await must always be called from an asynchronous function. It cannot be called from a non async function.

I think you will also need to use an await in front of getMatchesMethod();

Checkout this article for help with calling asynchronous code inside an useEffect()
https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-use-async-function-in-react-hook-useeffect-typescript-js-6204a788a435

Ex:

```js
const unsubcribe = navigation.addListener("willFocus", async () => {
    await getMatchesMethod();
});
```

Comment: the issue with this is  `An Effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up. It looks like you wrote useEffect(async () => ...) or returned a Promise. Instead, you may write an async function separately and then call it from inside the effect`